# Is it possible to create a map of vectors, where the vectors can be of any type?

Tags: c++

The key would be a string and the value would be a vector of any type.

For example the first key could map to a vector of ints and a second key could map to a vector of floats.  Is that possible in c++?

If not is there a way I could achieve a similar effect through some other means?

Comment: The more pressing question is why you think you need that.

Comment: Basically: no. Through other means? Absolutely. Why?

Comment: It can be done, but probably shouldn't. Is this purely academic, or ar you trying to do something?

Comment: @Beta I don't know how well I can explain it.  I have an opengl renderer currently written in java but being ported over to c++.  In this renderer I've tried to isolate the parts that can change specifically the buffers and shaders.  So I have a registerBuffer and registerShader function.  The registerBuffer function maps the shader variable name (a string) to the buffer.  But buffers could be GLfloat or GLushort.  So now I want to be able to map the shader variable name to a vector of GLfloat or GLushort.

Comment: @Xavier: You can use Boost.Variant, if it's just one of two types. This will give you much more type safety. However, there's no real way to get around using Boost. That's a feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could do it:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<boost::any> >
```

But it is very unlikely that this is what you actually want. Why do you think you need this?

> I have an opengl renderer currently written in java but being ported over to c++. In this renderer I've tried to isolate the parts that can change specifically the buffers and shaders. So I have a registerBuffer and registerShader function. The registerBuffer function maps the shader variable name (a string) to the buffer. But buffers could be GLfloat or GLushort. So now I want to be able to map the shader variable name to a vector of GLfloat or GLushort.

Well, you could use a `std::map<std::string, boost::variant<GLfloat, GLushort>>` then.

Comment: Or `map<string, boost::any>`...might be more efficient since it stores fewer discriminators.

Comment: @John: Possibly, but Xavier specifically asked about a mapping to vectors :)

Comment: Depends which is more important - that the values be constrained by type to be vectors, or that the vector once you find it is constrained by type to be homogeneous.

Comment: Not without seeing more code. Can you post the `registerBuffer` and `registerShader` functions?

Answer (score 2):

The boost::any solution seems like a hack to me. I recommend that you look into an object oriented design for your renderer.

What you need is a map that has string keys and buffers as values, correct? Then write a `Buffer` class, that can internally hold OpenGL buffers of any type, and make each instance keep track of what is the type of the buffer it holds. The data storage for this class could be a generic `void*` that is then cast to the proper type when the buffer needs to be sent to OpenGL.

Then, your data structure problem is fully resolved and you can do:

```
std::map<std::string, Buffer>
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

*Any* type? You could consider using [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/any.html). Then your type would be:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<boost::any> >
```

Comment: I think the elements in the vector need to be consistently types. Just different types of vector per key in the map.

Answer (score 1):

A `vector<T>`'s values must all be of the same type `T` and a `map<K,V>`'s values must all of type `V` which is `vector<T>` for some `T`, so no, not out of the box, but you can get around the type system with the [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/any.html) library.